# Background display incorrect in Android, Joomla

Tags: css, joomla, background, render

I have created a web page with Joomla and spoted that the background render's incorectly in Android.

I've set up a bakcground using CSS.

How can I fix it? P.S. I don't have much experience with web pages for mobile devices. Sorry.

Here is how it appears: [image: Bad render of the bakcground]

It has to be the same as on PC.

Thank you !!!

Comment: COMPARMOS TU .... Adv seems an image with fixed size. Can you make it's width as percentage or upload small image and try.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, but I don't think the Images are the problem, because you can see by the phone operator (top right corner) he is below the text, he has to be on the right side of the text. it is set as a I think this is because of some width... I cant get it to be fixed width.. the same happens when I change the resolution of the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fixed it by adding `min-width:1100px` css to the HTML tag.

Thank you all for the help !! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Arturas

Try using

```
#mainWrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
```

As Min-Width is ugly :P

Answer (score 0):

From the picture, what looks like is happening is the image is a jQuery scroller and is pushing the main container out?

as a quick fix you could just set `overflow:hidden`. This would cut 1/2 the image off though.
What would be best is to set the images ID to `width:100%` and the main scroller container as `width:100%` on your mobile CSS.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advise, but I have a fixed width of the images and I want to fix the size of the main wrapper so It wouldn't shrink, but I can't get that working with CSS... I'm trying, but if you have any advice please do tell. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, well if your having trouble figuring out what the container <div> is, on your browser(Google Chrome) right click the slider and click "inspect element" then find the very top "container div" you can find out its class name & what stylesheet it is under, then you can change the width inside the stylesheet. I would highly recommend to use width:100% though as phone / tablet sizes vastly vary.